# Объяснить поведение python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно, в следствие факапа, столкнулся с таким поведением.

```
examples = {
    "settings": [1, 2, 3],
    "params": ["abc", "abb"]
}

# фак ап был здесь (for example in) (Думал там if)
for example in examples.get("settings") and examples.get("params"):
    '''Для примера просто выведем, что получится в результате вызова'''
    print(example)
```

Comment: Ну просто `and` выполняется до `in`, можно посмотреть вывод `examples.get("settings") and examples.get("params")`

Comment: а что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Все работает. Что вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, у вас получилось, что цикл `for` собрался итерироваться по результату выражения `examples.get("settings") and examples.get("params")` которые оба списки. В Питоне не пустой список считается как `True` в логических выражениях.
А если левая часть операции `and` истина, то вычисляется правая часть, и она и будет результатом для выражения `список and список`. Потому по факту у вас всегда происходили итерации по второму списку, потому что первый был не пустой.

Вот несколько примеров результатов операций `and` и `or` над списками.

```
>>> [] and ['second']
[]

>>> ['first'] and ['second']
['second']

>>> [] or ['second']
['second']

>>> ['first'] or ['second']
['first']
```